# Create std::map of thread::id to Integer values

Tags: c++, multithreading

I would like to get the thread id associated with a known fixed integer rather than getting arbitrary id values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

std::mutex mu;
std::map<std::thread::id, int> threadIDs;

void run(int i) {
    std::unique_lock<mutex> map_locker(mu);
    std::cout << "Thread " << threadIDs.insert(std::make_pair(std::this_thread::get_id(), i)) << endl;
    map_locker.unlock();
}

int main() {
    std::thread the_threads[3]; //array of threads
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        //launching the threads
        the_threads[i] = std::thread(run, i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        the_threads[i].join();
    }
}
```

For instance:

```
Thread ID     Integer value
4             0
2             1
5             2
```

I get an error when running the above code:

> test.cpp:14:28: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream >' and
>             'pair' (aka 'pair<__map_iterator<__tree_iterator, std::__1::__tree_node, void *> *, long> >, bool>'))
>           std::cout << "Thread " << threadIDs.insert(std::make_pair(std::this_thread::get_id(), i)) << endl;

Comment: Note that it's not necessary to unlock `std::unique_lock` manually. It is designed to always unlock at the end of it's lifetime.

Comment: You don't actually *need* anything that `std::unique_lock` gives you. A `std::lock_guard` would be sufficient for your use.

Answer (score 4):

`std::pair` can't be printed via an `ostream` (look at the allowed types [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2)), so you need to print its members individually:

```
lock_guard<mutex> map_locker(mu);
pair<thread::id, int> p = make_pair(this_thread::get_id(), i);
threadIDs.insert(p);
cout << "Thread (" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ")" << endl;
```

---

Note that as pointed out by @FrançoisAndrieux, you don't need to manually `unlock` a [`unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock), as it automatically unlocks when it gets destructed (goes out of scope).

And as @JesperJuhl says, a [`lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) is better practice in this situation (it provides the minimum functionality you're looking for).